# Mocking Azure MobileServiceClient

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, azure-mobile-services

I have a method I need to Unittest and I am stuck with mocking part of it.

```
private async void LoginCommandAsync()
    {

        .....

        CancellationToken ct;
        var result = await ClientAuthorizationService.CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync(Constants.ApiConstants.AzureAuthMeData,
            null, HttpMethod.Get, null, ct);

        ....
    }
```

I tried to mock the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient using Moq. Unfortunatly I always get a System.InvalidCastException in the last code line

```
        var currentClient = new Mock<IMobileServiceClient>(MockBehavior.Loose);

        currentClient.Setup(x => x.InvokeApiAsync(Constants.ApiConstants.AzureAuthMeData,
            null, HttpMethod.Get, null, ct)).Returns(Task.FromResult(token));

        var disposableCurrentClient = currentClient.As<IDisposable>();

        ClientAuthorizationService.CurrentClient = (MobileServiceClient)disposableCurrentClient.Object;
```

MobileServiceClient inherits from IMobileServiceClient, IDisposable but no matter how I try to use/assign the mocked object... it does not work.

```
public class ClientAuthorizationService : IClientAuthorizationService
{
    public MobileServiceClient CurrentClient { get; set; }
    public ClientAuthorizationService()
    {
        CurrentClient = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApiConstants.ApplicationUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mocking `IMobileServiceClient` at no point is that interface going to be a `MobileServiceClient` class. This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: What is `ClientAuthorizationService` and `ClientAuthorizationService.CurrentClient`?

Comment: I am trying to Mock the MobileServiceClient because of the InvokeApiAsync that occurs in a method that I need to unittest. 
Currently the CurrentClient of type MobileServiceClient is a member/property of the ClientAuthorizationService which is an own implementation of the IClientAuthorizationService with no other dependencies

Comment: [edit] the question with a [mcve] the properly represents the problem to be solved so we can better help you.

Comment: as suggested, I edited my original question. Let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ClientAuthorizationService.CurrentClient` member/property from `MobileServiceClient` to `IMobileServiceClient`

```
public interface IClientAuthorizationService  {
    IMobileServiceClient CurrentClient { get; set; }
}

public class ClientAuthorizationService : IClientAuthorizationService {

    public ClientAuthorizationService() {
        CurrentClient = new MobileServiceClient(Constants.ApiConstants.ApplicationUrl);
    }

    public IMobileServiceClient CurrentClient { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow for a mock of the client to be assigned when testing as `ClientAuthorizationService` is now dependent on abstractions and not implementation concerns.

```
//....

var clientAuthorizationService = new Mock<IClientAuthorizationService>();

var currentClient = new Mock<IMobileServiceClient>();

currentClient
    .Setup(_ => _.InvokeApiAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), null, HttpMethod.Get, null, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(token);

clientAuthorizationService
    .Setup(_ => _.CurrentClient)
    .Returns(currentClient.Object);

//.....
```

Also it is advised not to use `async void` except for event handlers

So the code under test needs to be updated accordingly.

```
private async Task LoginCommandAsync() {

    //.....

    CancellationToken ct;
    var result = await ClientAuthorizationService.CurrentClient.InvokeApiAsync(Constants.ApiConstants.AzureAuthMeData,
        null, HttpMethod.Get, null, ct);

    //....
}
```

Comment: Where does Constants come from?

Comment: @Gerry The original question had it. Most likely they had some static classes with constant strings to use when calling the API. `public static class Constants { public class ApiConstants { public const string ApplicationUrl = "some URL here"; }}`